# Can't increment value of a floating-point variable

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, precision

I am newbie in C# and I can't understand, why my variable doesn't want to increment to value, bigger than 16777215.

I have code:

```
float fullPerc = 100;
float bytesRead = 1;
long fileSize = 1;
ProgressBar pb1;
int blockSizeBytes = 0;
float counter = 0;

using (FileStream inFs = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    fileSize = inFs.Length;
    do
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter > 16777215) //&& counter < 16777230)
        {
            counter = counter + 10;
            //Console.WriteLine(((counter + 10) /100));
        }
        count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes);
        offset += count;
        outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, count);

        bytesRead += blockSizeBytes;

   }
   while (count > 0);
   inFs.Close();
}
```

https://bitbucket.org/ArtUrlWWW/myfileencoderdecoder/src/f7cce67b78336636ef83058cd369027b0d146b17/FileEncoder/Encrypter.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Encrypter.cs-166

When value of the counter is equal 16777216, code of the variable increment `counter = counter + 1;` doesn't work, but this code

```
if (counter > 16777215) //&& counter < 16777230)
                                    {
                                        counter = counter + 10;
                                        //Console.WriteLine(((counter + 10) /100));
                                    }
```

is works fine.

Ie, if I comment this `if` code, my `counter` will grow up to 16777216 value and will stop on this value. Only increment by 10 will grow this variable, when this variable >=16777216 .

Why?

Comment: [Because floating points](http://ideone.com/UiLCPK). Floats have 7 digits of precision. You don't want to use a float for an integer counter.

Comment: Wait: You use float to represent integers? That's definitely unusual and nobody is going to find THIS bug easily.

Comment: Never use float for counters of any kind. They are NOT arbitrary precision. And that 16777216 thing is actually a limit (you'd need 24 bits for mantissa to properly increment yet you only have 23)

Comment: And what is the solution? :)

Comment: Use ints. :) Like int or uint.

Comment: Counters should always be of the type uint or similar (if you need negative counts, int; if you need unusually large numbers, use ulong/long)

Comment: And in general: Float and cryptography don't mix.

Comment: Not related to the question, but for what do you use that variable? Why do you need it to be a float?

Comment: I need it for calculation of the current progress, for progress bar. If I use in `float x = ((counter * blockSizeBytes) / fileSize) * fullPerc;` with int variables, it will not be calculated correctly, because of int is rounds values...

Comment: Why was the question downvoted ? he states he is new to programming, and he may have picked a hammer where a hammer is not suitable for the job, but his question resulted in exposing an interesting fact about floating point number in C# that I am sure many were not familiar with.

Comment: @Arthur Khusntudinov: change `float` into `int` (or even `long`) `int counter = 0;` and compute progress via `double x = (( (double)counter * blockSizeBytes) / fileSize) * fullPerc;`

Comment: Are you working with WPF or WinForms ProgressBar?

Comment: @CodeCaster - I think that's slightly unfair here. The poster is new to C#, reproducing to one line may not be obvious as they clearly aren't sure what part of the code is the part causing the issue. If they had one line and didn't show `counter` being a float, that would've caused further confusion for all of us and more comments to clarfiy. Fine question IMHO.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I didn't knew a root of the problem :). I thought, that may be some bug or incorrect settings of my project. But I have provided a full project on git (that's a very simple project), that you can run and test :) ❤.

Comment: @ArthurKhusntudinov - How precise do you need to this progress bar to be, is it just for the UI (in which case an long/int would suffice as the rounding won't affect it too much). Alternatively, instead of using an absolute progress bar for the entire file, could you have it display the percentage read instead since you have `fileSize` already? `((amountRead/fileSize) * 100)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thanks to all of you, people! Now I have become a little smarter and my code is working now! :) Peace! ❤

Comment: @ArthurKhusnutdinov - You're welcome. It may be worth posting your answer here for other people who might have a similar question and also you can then mark the thread as answered :)

Comment: @keyboardP, I can't post this answer, because it's not my answer, but community :). Moreover, Dmitry already answered. )

Comment: A developer needs to know why they are writing each line of code, in this case why the OP wrote `float`. This is what basic language and coding books are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mantissa *overflow* and as the result a *presision loss*. `float` (or `Single`) type has **24** bits mantissa (up to `16777216`):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Let's see what's going on:

```
  private static String MakeReport(float value) {
    return String.Join(" ", BitConverter
     .GetBytes(value)
     .Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
  }

...

  float f = 16777215;

  // Mantissa (first 3 bytes) is full of 1's except the last one bit
  // 11111111 11111111 01111111 01001011
  Console.Write(MakeReport(f)); 

  // Overflow! Presision loss
  // 00000000 00000000 10000000 01001011  
  Console.Write(MakeReport(f + 1)); 

  // Overflow! Presision loss
  // 00000000 00000000 10000000 01001011  
  Console.Write(MakeReport(f + 2)); 

  // Overflow! Presision loss
  // 00000100 00000000 10000000 01001011  
  Console.Write(MakeReport(f + 10));
```

Remedy: do not use *floating points* as `counter` but *integer*:

```
 int counter = 0;
```

To avoid *integer division* cast value into `double`

```
  float x = (float) ((((double)counter * blockSizeBytes) / fileSize) * fullPerc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dmitry!